# How to reset all the user rights in SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server

I have a question regarding the access of SQL Server.

I've shifted the server from one domain to other domain, SQL Server has no "local administrator" or "sa" access.

Can you please suggest how to login to SQL Server?

Thanks in advance,
Srinivas

Comment: Give [this](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2682/recover-access-to-a-sql-server-instance/) a try

Comment: This: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/connect-to-sql-server-when-system-administrators-are-locked-out?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: What exactly does "I've shifted the server" mean? Server refers to what? A sql server instance? An entire machine containing 1 or more sql server instances?

Comment: @SMor We have physically shifted the server from one domain to other.

Comment: As in you physically moved the machine itself to another location, in real life?

Answer (score 2):

If you've locked out all administrators and do not have access to the SA password (or the account is disabled), you can start SQL Server in "single-user" mode, which allows members of the local administrators group on a server to login to the server with sysadmin access to re-establish control.

Microsoft has thoroughly [documented the process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/connect-to-sql-server-when-system-administrators-are-locked-out?view=sql-server-2017), but the high-level process is as follows:

1. Logon to the server as a local administrator
2. Stop the SQL Server service for the affected instance
3. Start the SQL Server process from the command line using the -m switch
4. Connect to SQL Server using sqlcmd
5. Run a script to create a new login for an AD group/user and add it to the sysadmin role, OR reset the SA account password
6. Stop SQL Server and restart the service like normal

After this, you should be able to access the SQL Server instance and reconfigure any lower-level access that has also been broken following the domain move as required.

**EDIT:** I should state that I only know that this works on 2012-2019 instances, I don't know about earlier versions but I suspect the solution would be the same for 2005, 2008 and 2008 R2.

Answer (score 0):

If the solution with startup parameter -m fail for some reason you can try below:

1. Download PsExec https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec
2. Extract files
3. Start commandline as administrator
4. navigate to PsExec folder
5. Execute: psexec -i -s cmd.exe
6. In the cmd started by psexec use cmdsql -S (instance name) -E -q " command to create user and alter sysadmin role "

PsExec starting the cmd as local system that should have sysadmin role. By using it you should be able to create login with sysadmin role to regain access to the SQL Server.

As mentioned by John K. N. In SQL 2012 + by deafuls NT Authority\System is no longer a sysadmin. If that is the case here you can try also below solution with replacing SQLwriter

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4672/more-on-recovering-access-to-a-sql-server-instance/

Comment: This doesn't work for newer versions of SQL Server as the `NT-Authority\SYSTEM` account is not added to the `sysadmin`  server role per default.

Comment: you are right by default it is not sysadmin.

So the other solution can be to replace sqlwriter with sqlcmd like described here:

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4672/more-on-recovering-access-to-a-sql-server-instance/